# SSH another shell script from shell script

Tags: shell, ssh

I'm in `host1` and I want to shell script `shell1.sh` to execute another shell script `shell2.sh` in another host machine `host2`. Need to ssh for same.  Sorry, I'm little new to this scripting

So:

```
host1$ sh shell1.sh ----ssh---->  host2$ shell2.sh
```

Comment: On which machine is the `shell2.sh` file?

Answer (score 2):

On your `shell1.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh

ssh host2 '/bin/sh /path/to/shell2.sh'
```

And, if the `shell2.sh` file not on `host2`:

```
#!/bin/sh

ssh host2 < /path/to/shell2.sh
```

On the first alternative, you are passing to `ssh` a second argument, that it interprets as being a command to execute on the remote machine.

From `man ssh`:

> If **command** is specified, it is executed on the remote host instead of a login shell.

On the second script, the commands on `shell2.sh` are passed to the `ssh` command via stdin, which then forwards them to `host2`'s shell, finally executing them.

Answer (score 1):

You can doing this :

**local.sh** :

```
#!/bin/bash
hostname
whoami
ifconfig
```

Then, with your local script, you can run it remotely :

```
ssh host < local.sh
```

The `STDIN` shell of the remote host will be *connected* with the local shell script.